# Gimp - I don't seem to be able to arbitrarity move the edges of a selection anymore

Tags: gimp, selection, resizing

I'm certain I used to be able to arbitrarily move any of the four sides of a selection without the other sides changing, but I can't anymore.  When I click inside the selection and get the sizing bars displayed, when I use (e.g.) the bottom sizing bar to move the bottom edge, the top one moves also!

Likewise, I used to be able to pick up a corner and move it, but now the opposite corner moves as well.

I don't know whether I have accidentally changed a setting, but whatever it is, it's not nearly as useful anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Aahh... found it:

This was enabled:

[image]